# The render method in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Does the `render` method made available in Jest tests simply call `ReactDOM.render`?

Is the result some kind of intermediate representation of the eventual HTML?

Comment: I don't think Jest has any render method on it's API docs

Comment: I've been trying to find one in the source code and haven't been able to find it. As @Burimi also mentioned, it is not listed on the API here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. I guess this must be a global method in the project I am looking at.

Comment: @Ben I'm writing an answer for the sake of other members.

Answer (score 1):

So far Jest doesn't offer such a method. There is nothing related to that on [API](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html).

Enzyme has a feature like that, you can use [html()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/html.html) method of the wrapper.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Bar />);
const output = wrapper.html();
```